# Set field to true in JAVA

Tags: java, set, boolean

Wasn't sure how to search for this and was unable to find the answer to set the following to `true` (Java):

```
boolean flagRefund = true;
if (flagRefund){
    // Suppose to set wasRefunded field for user in DB to true or 1
    dbModelUser.getWasRefunded(); 
}
```

Comment: I really hope this is homework.

Comment: anything with "get" and not passing a value, gets a value, doesn't set anything. re-read the first chapters of your textbook. btw, your entire code is identical to: dbModelUser.getWasRefunded();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a lesson to teach you how to read the code if you see the method that starts with "get" then you use it to get some value from the method that returns it. When the method starts with "set" then this method usually returns `void` and takes parameters. Like this

```
boolean flagRefund = true;
if (flagRefund){
    // Suppose to set wasRefunded field for user in DB to true or 1
    dbModelUser.setWasRefunded(flagRefund); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, `get` methods are used to retrieve information, not to `set` information. Look if there is some `set` in your code method to achieve it.

Also, you don't pass any value to your method `getWasRefunded` as parameter so it is impossible that it could `set` any info.